# Make icons appear if variable is set

Tags: php, html

I created a config file for a template I am making. I am trying to make the social icons **only appear if the variable is set** so if they don't enter information for that icon it does not show in the line of icons.

I know that I can do it with an if statement but I would prefer not to have to make 12 if statements (one per icon)

here is the config section for the icons

```
/* ==========================================================================
   Social Media Acct. Information Below
   ========================================================================== */

/*** INLCUDE FULL URL FOR ALL FIELDS ***/

// Facebook
define('FACEBOOK_URL', '#');

// Twitter
define('TWITTER_URL', '#');

// Linkedin
define('LINKEDIN_URL', '#');

// Pinterest
define('PINTEREST_URL', '#');

// Google Plus
define('GOOGLE_URL', '#');

// Dribbble
define('DRIBBBLE_URL', '#');

// Youtube
define('YOUTUBE_URL', '#');

// Vimeo
define('VIMEO_URL', '#');

// Flickr
define('FLICKR_URL', '#');

// Yelp
define('YELP_URL', '#');

// Stumble Upon
define('STUMBLE_URL', '#');

//Specify icon color below (white or dark)

define('ICON_COLOR', 'white');
```

and here is the html for each icon

```
<div id="social_icons">
    <a href="#"><div class="icon_container" id="facebook_icon"></div></a>
    <a href="#"><div class="icon_container" id="twitter_icon"></div></a>
    <a href="#"><div class="icon_container" id="linkedin_icon"></div></a>
    <a href="#"><div class="icon_container" id="google_icon"></div></a>
    <a href="#"><div class="icon_container" id="pinterest_icon"></div></a>
    <a href="#"><div class="icon_container" id="dribble_icon"></div></a>
    <a href="#"><div class="icon_container" id="youtube_icon"></div></a>
    <a href="#"><div class="icon_container" id="vimeo_icon"></div></a>
    <a href="#"><div class="icon_container" id="flickr_icon"></div></a>
    <a href="#"><div class="icon_container" id="yelp_icon"></div></a>
    <a href="#"><div class="icon_container" id="stumbleupon_icon"></div></a>
</div>
```

I want to be able to accomplish this without placing an if statement around each link. Is there a way? Thanks!

**EDIT** Here is the new code snippets based on @thtjuan's answer if this helps answer the full question.

PHP

```
$social_links = array(

   'facebook'       => '#',

   'twitter'        => '#',

   'linkedin'       => '#',

   'google'         => '#',

   'pinterest'      => '#',

   'dribbble'       => '#',

   'youtube'        => '#',

   'vimeo'          => '#',

   'flickr'         => '#',

   'yelp'           => '#',

   'stumbleupon'    => '#'
);
```

HTML

```
<div id="social_icons">
     <?php foreach( $social_links as $icon => $url ): ?>
     <a href="<?php echo $url; ?>"><div class="icon_container" id="<?php echo $icon?>_icon"></div></a>
     <?php endforeach;?>
</div>
```

Comment: Try the (ifisset($var)) {
What happens...
}
This should work

Comment: you may have to use some javascript for this

Comment: @Max i know that would work but i would have to place one around each icon link and i don't want to have to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an array of links and then use a for loop to print them all:

e.g.

```
$links = array(
   'facebook' => '#',
   'twitter' => '#'
);
```

and then:

```
<div id="social">
  <?php foreach( $links as $icon => $url ): ?>
      <a href="<?php echo $url; ?>"><div class="icon_container" id="<?php echo $icon?>_icon"></div></a>
  <?php endforeach;?>
</div>
```

Note that any links that are not in the $links array will not show up at all on your page. If you must have all the entries in the array, then you can keep the ones without a url hidden by doing this:

```
<div id="social">
  <?php foreach( $links as $icon => $url ): ?>
      <?php if( strlen($url) && $url != '#' ): ?>
          <a href="<?php echo $url; ?>"><div class="icon_container" id="<?php echo $icon?>_icon"></div></a>
      <?php endif; ?>
  <?php endforeach;?>
</div>
```

Comment: that works fine except if there is no value defined it still shows the icon. I want the icon to not show unless the variable is set. Please see qustion

Comment: Not really.. this will only display icons for whatever entries are in the array. Do you mean you don't want the icon to show if $url == '#'?